# Structure First Child Redirect

Tags: structure

Anyone run into a navigation issue when using Structure's first child redirect?

I have a Blog page that redirects to the latest blog post when I just want it to go to /blog.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach your structure sitemap screenshot here?

Comment: @Mufi see above image. The first child redirect redirects the blog to a single entry post. I want it to just go to a blog page filled with snippet posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this script to your blog page then /blog url redirect to first child page.

```
{exp:structure:first_child_redirect}
```